# Uploading locally-created table to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload some data from a local server over to BigQuery. Since I'm new to working with BigQuery, I've been trying to just upload a few rows of sample data, but between all the available APIs and documentation, I've managed to get myself confused. If I'm trying to upload data that is being loaded via Java, and **not from a CSV file**, how would I go about loading it? Should I just write a POST request and sent it via HTTP, or create TableRows via the Java API and upload from there? I'm planning on using an OAuth key for all this. I'm sorry if this has already been answered somewhere, but I'm new to working with databases and could use the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You can import using a multipart http request. If you follow the directions here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/developers_guide#importingatable, and follow the instructions for where it says "importing from a local file". The heading is slightly misleading -- it shows the HTTP POST data format, and it doesn't matter where the data actually comes from (i.e. it doesn't have to be from a file).

Comment: That's the first method I wanted to try, but I got stuck setting up the HttpClient. I tried putting something together, but I've just been getting a 400 error that the media type "application/json" is not supported. What's the right way to do this with Google's HttpClient? I'd rather use the Apache client, but it seems that it doesn't support OAuth 2.0...